# How to write a if-controller condition for jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a situation where in the web app asks for security question the first time the user logs in, after which subsequent accesses mfa(security qns) are not asked. I added a if-controller but not sure what condition to write in it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to me that you could use a "Once Only Controller" instead of a "if controller".

For more info check [here at the jakarta jmeter site.](http://www.jajakarta.org/jmeter/1.7/en/user_manual/once_only.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
"${chargeback}" != "4"
```

here chargeback is variable based on the value of which if controller will decide the flow